# Check iOS device generation

Tags: ios, settings

How to check iOS device generation in its settings? If we go to **Settings › General › About › Version** then we see iOS version which is installed on device. How to check iOS device generation in similar way?

Answer (score 1):

Try UIDevice's [`systemVersion`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/systemVersion) property.

Answer (score 0):

Erica Sadun's [uidevice-extension](https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension) is useful for this.  In particular, see `UIDevice-Hardware.h`